# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 3 crashed when open .cs file from Windows Phone Toolkit?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, roslyn

After open some files on Windows Phone Toolkit sources the Visual Studio stopped working:

[image]

In Last record in ActivityLog.xaml there aren't any error but in windows error I've found some:

[image]

This is the full content of this error:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: An item with the same key has already been added.
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.ExceptionHelpers.CrashUnlessCanceled(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass30`1+<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__33>d__0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass30`1+<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__33>d__0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass30`1+<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__33>d__0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__33>d__0<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass30`1+<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__33>d__0[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__33>d__0<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass30`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__33(System.__Canon, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__1`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__1`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__1`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__1`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__1`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor.GetOrDefaultAsync[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon, System.Func`3<System.__Canon,System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__1`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__1`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__1`1<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__1`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__1`1<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__1`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__1`1<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor.RunAnalyzersAsync[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.IIncrementalAnalyzer>, System.__Canon, System.Func`4<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.IIncrementalAnalyzer,System.__Canon,System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<ProcessDocumentAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<ProcessDocumentAsync>d__1, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<ProcessDocumentAsync>d__1 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<TryProcessOneHigherPriorityDocumentAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<TryProcessOneHigherPriorityDocumentAsync>d__1, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<TryProcessOneHigherPriorityDocumentAsync>d__1 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor.TryProcessOneHigherPriorityDocumentAsync()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<ExecuteAsync>d__1, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<ExecuteAsync>d__1 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.WorkCoordinatorRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.IdleProcessor+<ProcessAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.IdleProcessor+<WaitForIdleAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+DelayPromise.Complete()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<Delay>b__17(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireQueuedTimerCompletion(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Do you know how I can fix that problem ?

Comment: That looks like https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/52.  Disable Roslyn, switch to Dev14, or remove the duplicate supression message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/52.

Disable Roslyn, switch to Dev14, or remove the duplicate supression message.